Low performance when receiving large amounts of data from tarantool
There is a task to get a large enough amount of data for certain purposes. Usually it's 2-4 million records, which I retrieve from various SQL tables.
I'm not happy with the time taken to retrieve the data, so I want to use an in-memory database but leave the ability to run SQL queries, which I've tried using tarantool for.
Since the database needs to be integrated with a python project, I'm using the python connector https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-python.
Loading and unloading large amounts of data is not a standard use of tarantool, but I thought that due to the very high speed of inserting and retrieving individual records there would be no performance issues. However, even retrieving 500,000 tuples from 1 space already has performance issues and there is no big gain in retrieval speed compared to postgres.
Instance is configured in the most basic way on a local machine, memtx_memory = 2048 Mb
To solve these problems, I tried offloading the data in batches.
To offload data in batches, I created a test time space into which I moved certain data from the space where I had made previous measurements:
import tarantool


tarantool_config = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': 3301,
    'user': 'user',
    'password': 'password',
}


def create_and_fill_temp_space():
    conn = tarantool.connect(**tarantool_config)

    create_temp_space = "box.schema.space.create('temp_space', {temporary = true})"
    conn.eval(create_temp_space)

    configure_temp_space = f"""
    box.space.temp_space:format({{
        {{name = 'id', type = 'unsigned'}},
        {{name = 'data', type = 'any'}}
    }})
    box.space.temp_space:create_index('primary', {{
        type = 'tree',
        parts = {'id'},
        if_not_exists = true
    }})
    """
    conn.eval(configure_temp_space)

    lua_query = f"""
    local fiber = require('fiber')

    for i, row in ipairs(box.space.test_space.index.someid_idx:select{{{id}}}) do
        box.space.temp_space:insert{{i, row}}
        if i % 100 == 0 then
            fiber.yield()
        end
    end
    """
    conn.eval(lua_query)

    conn.close()

Then I unload data from the temporary space by registering a function in tarantool.
box.schema.func.create('fetch_all_records', {
    body = [[
        function(page_size)
            local result = {}
            local start_key = nil

            while true do
                local page = {}

                if start_key == nil then
                    for _, tuple in box.space.temp_space.index.primary:pairs(nil, {iterator = 'GE'}) do
                        table.insert(page, tuple)
                        if #page >= page_size then
                            break
                        end
                    end
                else
                    for _, tuple in box.space.temp_space.index.primary:pairs(start_key, {iterator = 'GT'}) do
                        table.insert(page, tuple)
                        if #page >= page_size then
                            break
                        end
                    end
                end

                if #page == 0 then
                    break
                end

                for _, tuple in ipairs(page) do
                    table.insert(result, tuple)
                end

                start_key = page[#page][1]
            end

            return result
        end
    ]],
    if_not_exists = true
})

And using it later.
@measuring_time
def fetch_data_from_temp_space(space_name):
    conn = tarantool.connect(**tarantool_config)

    page_size = 1000
    result = conn.call('fetch_all_records', page_size)
     
    conn.close()

The retrieval time remains the same as if I had run a normal query to retrieve all the data from the space. What could be the error? Maybe I need to get some in batches in a different way?

Recently I performed several experiments with 89K rows, 5MB responses from one tarantool storage to many clients. I see that the TX thread consumes 100% CPU on encoding Lua tables to msgpack (better if it is a table of box tuples, but still suboptimal). A practical solution would be acquire the data directly without Lua, using IPROTO_SELECT request (.select() in tarantool-python), using SQL, using a C procedure (box_index_iterator() + box_iterator_next() + box_return_tuple()) or using some prepared msgpack.object() object. Also I suggest to glance on asynctnt connector for python.
